# Python Django Export CSV with Japanese Text

Tags: python, django, csv, encoding, encode

Export CSV Problem

```
#==================================
Python 2.7.6
Django 1.7
#==================================

# Get from MySQL
{'SearchItem_1_JP': u'\u30a2\u30af\u30bb\u30b5\u30ea\u30fc'} # アクセサリー
searchitem_1_jp = searchitem['SearchItem_1_JP']

# Output CSV
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="test_export.csv"'
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('utf8')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('U8')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('UTF')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('utf8')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('utf_8_sig')])

writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('ascii', 'ignore')])        

writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('cp932')])

writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('euc_jp')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('euc_jis_2004')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('euc_jisx0213')])

writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('iso2022_jp')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('iso2022_jp_1')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('iso2022_jp_2')])

writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('iso2022_jp_2004')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('iso2022_jp_3')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('iso2022_jp_ext')])

writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('shift_jis')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('shift_jis_2004')])
writer.writerow([searchitem_1_jp.encode('shift_jisx0213')])

return response
```

==================================

I have tried all codec method for Japanese.
However, the exported CSV file's data are still garbled.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codec-base-classes

Comment: How did you fix it? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in csv library is not unicode compliant. You can try the drop-in replacement [unicodecsv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv)